# CMake: proper way to handle dependencies which require cmake themself ( crossplatform )

Tags: c++, cmake, organization

What is the proper way to structure a project with dependencies that don't offer pre-build binaries ( or if you would want to build the dependencies yourself )

Normally I structure my projects as follows

```
/root/
 - Dependencies/
 - ...Subdirs...
 - Output/
 - CMakeLists.txt
```

Which is then cmade into the `Output/`, If an library is already build usually you can simply use `find_package` to use it as an dependency.

However if cmake has not been executed for each dependency, they won't have an `<PackageName>Config.cmake` and can thus not be found using `find_package`.

So the question is how do you organize a project if you want/have to build a dependency from source, on multiple platforms.

- Use a script which builds all the dependencies
- Make a cmake target which does something similar
- Something else

And what if a dependency has another dependency which needs to be build as well.

Also for `.ignore` files it would be better if all dependencies where build/cmade into the `Output/` directory

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html might help

Comment: I usually just call `add_subdirectory` on the directory of the dependency. I haven't had any issues yet.

Answer (score 0):

Commonly libraries' `CMakeLists.txt` is configured to introduce a *library* target. That means that you can just add it to your own project and use *almost* the same way you use `find_package` dependencies. Assuming the project directory is something like this:

```
.
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- build
|-- src
|-- libs
|   |-- lib1Folder
|   `-- lib2Folder
```

And provided `lib1` and `lib2` have `CMakeLists.txt` configuration in their corresponding folders (`lib1Folder` and `lib2Folder`), you add them in your own `CMakeLists.txt` as follows:

```
add_subdirectory(libs/lib1Folder)
list(APPEND LIB_TARGETS lib1)
list(APPEND LIB_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/lib1Folder/include")

add_subdirectory(libs/lib2Folder)
list(APPEND LIB_TARGETS lib2)
list(APPEND LIB_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/lib2Folder/include")


target_include_directories(MyExecutable SYSTEM PRIVATE ${LIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(MyExecutable PRIVATE ${LIB_TARGETS})
```

Where `MyExecutable` is name of the target you want to link the dependencies with. Of course different libs may have different configuration (some libs make include folders variable themselves, others may not do that and also don't have the `include` folder explicitly given), but this works for me personally most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

If the project is a cmake project, you can add it as a subdirectory and add it to the build with:

```
add_subdirectory(<src-dir> <build-dir>)
```

After that you can add the build targets as dependency to your project, so that cmake will build them if not present.`For example if you want to use cpputest in your project, you add it to` Dependencies/cpputest` and add it in cmake with

```
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/cpputest ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cpputest)
```

All targets of cpputest will be build in a subdirectory in your build directory. After that you can add the cpputest library as dependency

```
target_link_libraries(my_binary CppUTest)`
```

If you build the `my_binary`, cpputest will be build automatically.

You can have a look at a project, where I used this: https://github.com/sweintritt/cora

Dependencies are added as submodules in the subdirectory `third_party` and added to the build in `cmake/dependencies.cmake`. The external build targets are then used in `cmake/cora.cmake`